# How to leave perl debug API programmatically?

Tags: perl, debugging

I have following script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar { foo() }
sub foo { }
sub hello { bar(); }
hello();
```

I run it with non-interactive debugger and got:

```sh
$ PERL5OPT=-d PERLDB_OPTS='N f=1' perl 2.pl
Package 2.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering main::hello
   entering main::bar
    entering main::foo
```

Now I want to stop printing stacktrace by disabling debugger after `bar()` call. How to do that ?

What I tried:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar {
# $^D;                                  # no effect
# DB::done();                           # Undefined subroutine &DB::done
# $DB::finished=1;                      # no effect
# delete $INC{'perl5db.pl'};            # no effect
# Class::Unload->unload('perl5db.pl');  # no effect
foo();
}
sub foo { }
sub hello { bar(); }
hello();
```

But `entering main::foo` still printed.

Expected output:

```
Package 2.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering main::hello
   entering main::bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really disable the debugger once it's started. You can, however, stop the printing of subroutine calls.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar {
    $DB::frame = 0;
    foo();
}
sub foo { }
sub hello { bar(); }
hello();
```

Output:

```
Package try.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering main::hello
   entering main::bar
```

---

If you want to use the big hammer and redefine `DB::sub`, you need to do something like this:

```
sub bar {
    {
        package DB;
        no warnings 'redefine';
        no strict;
        *sub = sub { &$sub };
    }
    foo();
}
```

However, this also means you can't re-enable call tracing at a later point in the script.

Comment: thanks for participating in discussion. Seems like I found better way, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Seems like we can just clear `DB::sub` : `*DB::sub = sub {};`

```
$ cat 2.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
sub bar {
*DB::sub = sub {};
foo();
}
sub foo { }
sub hello { bar(); }
hello();

$ PERL5OPT=-d PERLDB_OPTS='NonStop frame=1' perl 2.pl
Package 2.pl.
  entering DB::Obj::_init
  entering main::hello
   entering main::bar
```

Thanks to [Enbugger perldoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger#Unloading-the-debugger).

Comment: That doesn't really work. Not only does it disable tracing, it disables subroutine calls altogether. `foo` is never entered.

Comment: Could you please explain details ? I thought just `*DB::sub` disabled, not `*sub`

Comment: I tested it by changing `foo` to `sub foo { die 42 }` and the program never died. As far as I can tell, `DB::sub` is invoked not *before* a subroutine is called, but *instead* of it. The implementation of `DB::sub` in the standard debugger then arranges for the actual call to happen. Your script turns `DB::sub` into a no-op, so all following subroutine calls never happen. (Also, you've made it impossible to re-enable call tracing at a future point in the script.)

Comment: Enbugger perldoc tell us that we can unload debugger by clearing the `DB::` package. https://metacpan.org/pod/Enbugger#Unloading-the-debugger What is the correct way of doing it by your opinion ?

Comment: As it says right there: "*You wish. There is no implemented way to unload the debugger. Here's how you'd do it if you wanted to implement this feature.*" And then it lists three things you'd have to do to add this feature to Enbugger. Clearing `DB::` is only step 2 of 3.

Comment: Isn't it 3 alternative options ?

Comment: No, it's a ToDo list for extending Enbugger.